# Plaid identity - sandbox

Tags: dwolla, plaid

Has anyone been able to use plaid identity in sandbox?  I would like to use plaid identity to help provide info to get a customer verified using dwolla.

I keep getting this error message

> Error Type : INVALID_INPUT
>   Error Code : INVALID_PRODUCT
>   Error Message : client is not authorized to access the following products: ["identity"]
>   Display Message :  Request ID : LoUfi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link below also shows that you aren't able to access the "identity" feature using the Plaid test credentials.

https://dashboard.plaid.com/overview/sandbox

You may be able to access it if you request specific API keys for the 100 free live connections specified in the pricing.

https://plaid.com/pricing/